# How to disable Apache ErrorDocument Message

Tags: apache, errordocument

I need to disable Apache 401 error message or bypass it completely , in case of errors only back end application error codes should be displayed.

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following to your .htaccess file (works if AllowOverride allows it).

ErrorDocument 401 /URL/TO/YOUR/BACKEND/RESPONSE

Custom error documents are configured using the ErrorDocument directive, which may be used in global, virtualhost, or directory context.

[More info about Apache ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument)